# Insert row tableview with a button at last section

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to make a tableview with a button in the section. I want the button to add one more row to a tableview like this

[image]

Here is the source code:

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection sectionInd: Int) -> Int {
    if sectionInd == 0 {
    return others.count
        } else {
    return 1
        }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShareCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SelectOthersTableViewCell
    cell.firstName.text = others[indexPath.row].firstname
    cell.lastName.text = others[indexPath.row].lastname
    return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! addTableCell
            cell.addCells.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.addCells.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OthersViewController.addButtonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var height:CGFloat = CGFloat()
   if indexPath.section == 0 {
        height = 145
   } else {
        height = 50
    }
    return height
}

@objc func addButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    data.append("Guest 1")
    let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    print("indexPath \(indexPath!)")
    selectedIndexes[indexPath!] = !(selectedIndexes[indexPath!] ?? false)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: data.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

i need help please. How to add new row by tap button on icon (+)?

Comment: how did you add the rest of the rows? the procedure is pretty much identical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of "Add" button, You **should not** reload the the entire table view because it increases the processing time. Instead of that you can use of 
 **beginUpdates** and **endUpdates** for inserting new cell when button clicked.

#### Basic Approaches:

(1). On click of "Add", update your data-source for table-view.

```
dataSource.append(NewRecord)
```

(2). Insert the new cell:

```
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: dataSource.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

#### Reviewing your Code:

```
func addButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
  data.append("Guest 1")
  .....
}
```

Your datasource is **others** on which the tableview is created and configured.
But on click of add button (**addButtonClicked** function), you are not updating the **others** data-source. Please verify it, except that your code seems good.

Comment: i get error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

```
fun onPlusButtonClicked(){
    sections.append(whatever you want)
    items[2].append(["1", "2", "3", "4"]) // whatever you want to add here
    tableview.reloadData() // you can call this on a background thread as well, if its not working
}
```

// Ex of how to use with tableview

```
var sections = Your array

var items = your array

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}
```

Comment: What error did you got ??
Also I can see you using "others" as your array while using number of rows. But you did not used same array in addButtonClicked

Comment: Also why did you need this ??
  let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

Comment: the error is libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: my array is var data = ["Guest 1"] and var others : Results<Others>!. where orhers is result from realm. where do I place the array?

Comment: you need to understand your requirement. And understand my answer and re do some work. ex
change section like
var sec:int
sec = 2

and in button click just increase section
sec = sec +1

Similarly just update your code